# C# Excel crashes when deleting worksheet

Tags: c#, excel

I have a windows form that when it opens it creates a worksheet. When it Closing it is to delete that worksheet. I store the worksheet called ws in a private variable.  Excel crashes and doesn't throw an exception when deleting this sheet. I found a few unresolved answers on this topic. any help is appreciated.

```
        xl.Application xlApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        try
        {
            ws.Delete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
```

Comment: Is it the only worksheet in the workbook? That's the most common delete worksheet crash reason I've seen.

Comment: no there this is an add in. it creates a new sheet when opening the winform.